# Merge two tables common and uncommon columns based on intervals of data SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would love some help to solve my problem below please!

I have two SQL Server tables which I would like to merge into one result table. Table 1 has larger intervals (DistanceFrom - DistanceTo) than Table 2 so I am dealing with overlapping intervals. Sometimes it is perfect match for DistanceFrom and DistanceTo but other times not.

I would like to display the Table1.code associated to each Sample in the result table, knowing the DistanceFrom and DistanceTo can vary.

**Table 1:**

[image]

**Table 2:**

[image]

**Desired result table:**

[image]

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

I managed to merge the 2 tables but always end up with some `NULL` in my Table1.Code result table as I struggle to split the intervals from Table 1 when required. The only time I don't have NULL is when the DIstanceFrom and Distance2 from table 1 are matching the ones from Table2.

Or I have managed to merge but I am missing some 'Sample' (missing the intervals not matching DistanceFrom and Distance To basically)

**To Ravi**
Hi Ravi and thanks for your quick answer. I think I may not have been clear enough and below is a better example with the results expected: So far I have managed to get most of my intervals using a different query but I have intervals still missing. The sample should be duplicated in some occasion like for U2 but the matching distancefrom and distanceTo should be different when there is a sample reapeat due to an overlapping code if it makes sense?

```
   CREATE TABLE table1 ( Code VARCHAR(10) NULL ,DistanceFrom INT NULL ,DistanceTo INT NULL )
    
CREATE TABLE table2 ( Sample VARCHAR(10) NULL ,DistanceFrom INT NULL ,DistanceTo INT NULL ) INSERT INTO table1 VALUES ('A',68.04 ,74.58), ('B',74.58 ,74.85), ('C', 74.85, 75.07),('D', 75.07, 81.07)
    
INSERT INTO table2 VALUES ('U1',74 ,74.58), ('U2',74.58 ,75.07), ('U3', 75.07, 76), ('U4',76 ,77)
```

Below would be the results I would like to get:

Sample DistanceFrom DistanceTo Table1.Code U1 74 74.58 A
U2 74.58 74.85 B
U2 74.85 75.07 C
U3 75.07 76 D
U4 76 77 NULL

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please take a minute to read the [tour] and another minute to read the [sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info) tag info, and [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query:

##### DDL

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  Code VARCHAR(10) NULL
  ,DistanceFrom INT NULL
  ,DistanceTo INT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE table2 (
  Sample VARCHAR(10) NULL
  ,SDistanceFrom INT NULL
  ,SDistanceTo INT NULL
)

INSERT INTO table1 
VALUES ('C1',3 ,9), ('C2',9 ,10), ('C3', 10, 13)

INSERT INTO table2 
VALUES ('S1',3 ,4), ('S2',4 ,6), ('S3', 6, 9), ('S4',9 ,11), ('S5', 11, 13)
```

##### Select Query

```
SELECT t2.Sample
  ,IIF(t1.DistanceFrom >= t2.SDistanceFrom, t1.DistanceFrom, t2.SDistanceFrom) AS RDistanceFrom
  ,IIF(t1.DistanceTo <= t2.SDistanceTo, t1.DistanceTo, t2.SDistanceTo) AS RDistanceTo
  ,t1.Code
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2
  ON t2.SDistanceFrom BETWEEN t1.DistanceFrom AND t1.DistanceTo - 1
    OR t2.SDistanceTo BETWEEN t1.DistanceFrom + 1 AND t1.DistanceTo
ORDER BY t2.Sample, t1.Code
```

##### Explanation

1. **JOIN:** We are joining table1 and table2 in such way that if there is any overlap between `DistanceFrom - DistanceTo` and `SDistanceFrom - SDistanceTo`
2. **SELECT:**

   - `RDistanceFrom`: Maximum of `DistanceFrom` and `SDistanceFrom`
   - `RDistanceTo`: Minimum of `DistanceTo` and `SDistanceTo`

Please check [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c4590/8) and tweak your query incase it needs any change.

Regards,
Ravi

Comment: Hi and thanks for your quick answer. I am not sure I was clear enough, but below is with a better example: